# How to rewrite this code using bit field(struct)

Tags: c++, struct, bit, bit-fields

I need to get access to high bit,low bit and digit bit of the number that is signed short type,using structures.
Have no idea about it,was surfing Internet,but there is not much info about signed short.

I tried to run it using some functions,but my task is to use bit field...

```
    void print(signed short num)

    {
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
    if (num&(1 << i))
    cout << i << " bit is 1" << endl;
    else
    cout << i << " bit is 0" << endl;

}
cout << "Your number is:" << num << endl;

    }

    int main() {
signed short num;
cout << "Please, enter your number:";
cin >> num;
print(num);
if (num&(1 << 15))
    cout << "Your number is negative" << endl;
else
    cout << "Your number is positive" << endl;

return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of an anonymous `union` and bitfields to achieve the desired behavior :

```
union bit_access {
    int16_t as_short;
    struct {
        uint8_t bit15 : 1;
        // Continue until :
        uint8_t bit0 : 1;
    };
};

 // You can then access individual bits using :
 bit_access b = { -1234 };
 std::cout << "bit 0 = " << (int) b.bit0 << std::endl;
```

Be aware that, if i recall correctly :

- The size of `unsigned short` it's not guaranteed to be 16
- Bitfield `struct`s are not guaranteed to be represented without padding, you may need to use something like `__attribute__((packed))__`, which is compiler specific.